# Submit edited columns of grid Ext JS

Tags: extjs, grid

So I have a `grid` which looks like this

```
itemId: 'someGrid',
xtype: 'grid',
title: 'Some Grid',
store: 'SomeStore',
selType: 'cellmodel',
plugins: [
   Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
       clicksToEdit: 2
   })
],
columns: [
                { text: 'column1', dataIndex: 'dataIndex1', flex: 2.7 },
                { xtype: 'checkcolumn', text: column2, dataIndex: 'dataIndex2', flex: 2.7 },
                { xtype: 'checkcolumn', text: column3, dataIndex: 'dataIndex3', flex: 3 },
                { 
                    text: column4, dataIndex: 'dataIndex4', flex: 3.85,
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'combobox',
                        itemId: 'someCOmbo',
                        store: 'SomeStoreOfCombo',
                        displayField: 'DataName',
                        valueField: 'DataId',
                        allowBlank: false,
                        editable: false,
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: column5, dataIndex: 'dataIndex5', flex: 3,
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        allowBlank: false,
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: column6, dataIndex: 'dataIndex6', flex: 3.1,
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        allowBlank: false,
                    }
                },
                { text: column7, dataIndex: 'dataIndex7', flex: 1.7 },
                { dataIndex: 'Id', hidden: true }
            ],
```

both `checkcolumns` and `column4` 5 and 6 are editable. I have button under the grid to submit changes. So how do I get all the changed that were made to the grid so that than I can submit it ?

Comment: Do you still need help on this question?  Do you just want to know how to get the records that are marked as changed?

Answer (score 0):

this edits directly so you don't need a button:

`plugins:[  Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing',{clicksToEdit: 2,
Listeners:[edit: function(editor, e){if (e.value !== e.originalValue) {this.someGrid.getStore().getById(e.record.data.ID).commit();}}]})],`

maybe needs to be adjusted a bit since I'm usually using Ext.Net and just tried to translate. But you should get the idea behind it ;)

if you want the button use `<store>.sync();` as clickhandler

(edit: i somehow don't get linebreaks to work - can someone please edit it?)